# how to close-pack html elements in 2D space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to close-pack html boxes that that are dynamically generated, meaning that their size can't be predicted. And I want to do this WITHOUT using javascript.
Here is an example that does NOT work in the way that I want it to:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#information { border: 3px solid orange;}
.abs { float: left; width: 15em; height: 10em; background-color: pink; }
.two  { width: 12.5em; height: 12.5em; background-color: lightblue; }
.three  { width: 10em; margin-top:;height: 10em; background-color: lightgreen; }
.clear { clear: both; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="information" style="width:28em">
<div class="abs">1</div>
<div class="abs two">2</div>
<div class="abs three">3</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here there is a vertical gap between the "1" and the "3" box that I want to remove. In this example I could just do this:

```
<div class="abs three" style="margin-top:-2.5em">3</div>
```

But in the general case I don't know the sizes of the single boxes nor the size of the surrounding box.

Is there a way of doing this using only html + CSS or is there not?

Comment: If you don't know the sizes in advance then no, you're stuck having to use JavaScript